# Default ownership and permissions on root directory Synology DSM

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, nas

I was trying to setup the Git server for Synology DSM 6.2 and to do so, I logged in via SSH using the `root` user (switching from the admin account during the SSH session).

While setting up the folder to contain the repos, I unfortunately ran `chown -R gituser:administrators .` not on the directory for the repos but instead in the root directory itself, changing the ownership of the root directory to the gituser account. I realized this mistake immediately and ran `chown -R root:root .` which I supposed to be the correct ownership. However, I don't know, if this ownership and permission setting is correct now.

Running `ls -al` as the root user (after running `cd`) gives me the following ownership and permissions:

```
root@NAS:~# ls -al
total 32
drwx------  4 root root 4096 Jul  8 20:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 26 root root 4096 Dec 17 11:26 ..
-rw-------  1 root root   16 May 15  2019 .esd_auth
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Jul  8 20:20 .gnupg
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1113 Mar 31  2019 .profile
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Dec 17 11:28 .pulse
-rw-------  1 root root  256 May 15  2019 .pulse-cookie
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  320 Nov 11 12:59 .wget-hsts
```

Right now, my NAS seems to run stable and I did not notice any changes but I want to avoid problems in the future, so I was wondering if someone could tell me, if these are the correct ownership and permission settings for this directory. Otherwise, I would probably reinstall DSM to avoid any problems.